# How come the first version of my function returns a different value from the second version of my function?

Tags: python

I dont understand why the second version works. With the first paragraph of code the output is `"1.1.1.1"`, with the second paragraph of code the output is `1[.]1[.]1[.]1`, How come this is so? why doesnt the first paragraph print out the same thing as the second one?

ive tried everything

```
class Solution:
    def defangIPaddr(self, address: str) -> str:
        '''
        takes in a str variable called address
        returns a string
        '''
        address.replace('.','[.]')
        return address

class Solution:
    def defangIPaddr(self, address: str) -> str:
        '''
        takes in a str variable called address
        returns a string
        '''
        return address.replace('.','[.]')
```

I expect the output to be `1[.]1[.]1[.]1` in the first version of the function of code.

Comment: The first one does not do anything, since it produces a new string, but you throw that away.

Comment: `str` objects are immutable, every `str` method *returns a new `str` object*

Answer (score 1):

In Python (and many other programming languages) **strings are *immutable***. That means that you can not change the content of a string, you can only create a new string that is a modified copy of the original one.

This thus means that `address.replace('.','[.]')` does *not* change the `address` string, it creates a *new* string that is returned by that method. But in your first function, you ignore that result. This thus means that you simply return the original string.

By using `return address.replace('.','[.]')`, you thus return the result of that function call, a string where the `.` is replaced by `[.]` compared to the original string.